# Java IOException InfiniteLoop

Tags: java

I have this method and I want to check for user input. If it is a number but greater than 9 and lees than 1 or Char / String I want to throw an Exception. With the numbers it works but when I want to check for char/Strings it goes in infinite loop.

```
private static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

public static int getPlayerPositionInput(String message)     {
    System.out.println(message);
    while(true) {
        System.out.println("1");
        try {
            if(in.hasNextInt()){
                int i = in.nextInt();
                if(i<1 || i>9 ) throw new IOException();
                return i;
            } else throw new IOException();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("The number has to be greater than 0 and less than 10");
        }
    }
}
```

I was thinking about using ASCII table, would it be a good idea ?

Answer (score 2):

If you enter a `String` then `if(in.hasNextInt()){` will always be false and hence no input will be possible.

Try using `hasNext` and `nextLine`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that after you submit the non-numeric string, `hasNextInt()` returns `false`. But scince you do not discard the wrong input, it will return `false` the next time it is called, too.

Try this:

```
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("1");
        try {
            if (in.hasNext()) {
                if (in.hasNextInt()) {
                    int i = in.nextInt();
                    if (i < 1 || i > 9) {
                        throw new IOException();
                    }
                    return;
                } else {
                    in.next(); // discard the input
                    throw new IOException();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("The number has to be greater than 0 and less than 10");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank You. Now I can clearly see it. The problem was that:Firstly - I didn't read documentation carefully Secondly - I forgot that it keeps to the previous input so I have to discard current one and look for next....

Comment: + I think here we don't need in.hasNext()

Comment: Maybe. But the general contract is, that next() should only be called after hasNext() to avoid an unwanted exception.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are catching the exception and going for next loop.

Exception is Super Class to IOException. Go through below documentation.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html

Your exception catching logic needs to be refactored.